# Install package in separate area for read-only Anaconda Linux install

Tags: anaconda

at work we have a central, read-only, Linux Anaconda installation, and several projects need library packages for their individual project members.
Is there a way to conda install packages in a writable area set aside for each project?

Our Linux servers are also not directly web connected, but we can transfer data from a Windows machine that is. Is there a way for the windows conda to download data for our Linux install in such a way that I can transfer the downloaded files to Linux and then finish the install on Linux , with the conda linux not needing a direct web connection?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer to this question is a bit oblique: the Anaconda Distribution is designed for a single user on a single system with unrestricted access to the Internet.  Any other use is considered "off label" and YMMV, though there are no license restrictions in place preventing you from trying to use it as you see fit.  Anaconda Enterprise is the commercial product that is specifically designed for multi-user, server-deployed Anaconda with firewall restrictions.  Security, governance, indemnification, support, collaboration, etc. etc. Check out https://www.continuum.io/ for more details.

But there are "work around" ways to achieve what you want, albeit complicated ones.  For it to be reliable, reproducible, and maintainable you're going to end up reimplementing a lot of what is in Anaconda Enterprsie.  Here are some tips:

- Check out the ["conda in multi-user environments" documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/admin-multi-user-install.html)
- Check out the ["Centralized Anaconda installation" documentation](https://docs.continuum.io/docs_oss/conda/install/central)
- Regular user `alice` for project `foo` can do `conda create -p /nfs/project/foo/envs/custompython --offline anaconda; conda activate /nfs/project/foo/envs/custompython; conda install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3`
- You're going to run into ownership/permission issues.  If you have sensible `umask` values then when `alice`'s colleague `bob` tries to update `pkg2` in the `foo` project he'll discover that he can't unlink the files `alice` wrote there.  There is stuff you can do (as the IT admin) with `chown`, or `alice` can do with `chmod`, but its all a bit of a bother and there are lots of ways you can paralyze a conda environment because it is expecting "writability" to be binary for a particular environment.  There is a long history in the conda GH issue tracker of people (myself included) shooting themselves in the foot by starting a conda env setup with one account and then making mods with another account that bork out half way through, leaving everything inconsistent.
- Be careful about `.condarc` files.  My advice: avoid them everywhere but in the base Anaconda installation (say, inside `/opt/anaconda/.condarc`).  All sorts of weird stuff can happen when multiple overlaying .condarc files come together (the docs reference above discusses this).
- People can create their own environments in an "offline" mode so long as the packages specified in those new environments (and their dependencies) are a subset of the packages available in the base environment (or subsequently added to the package cache), taking into account versions as well, of course.
- You can download packages using your online Windows machine by grabbing them from `repo.continuum.io` and from `anaconda.org`.  Make sure you download them for the right platform.  But the challenge: you need to download a set of packages that will satisfy the dependencies of the package you want to install.  There isn't a super easy way to get that information when you're offline.
- Once you drop new packages into the Linux system's package cache be sure to re-run [`conda index`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/build/conda-index.html).
- Beware installing packages directly from their tarballs: this will not pick up any dependencies and does what is called a "force" install.  So doing `conda install /path/to/conda/pkg-ver.tar.bz2` is actually most similar to doing `conda install --force --no-deps pkg=ver` (though not identical, to be sure).  `--force` means the install will happen NO MATTER WHAT, even if it will break your environment (violate existing package dependencies), and `--no-deps` means you won't get any of the dependencies of `pkg` installed.